# Julian Date Converter using Javascript/Node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a Julian Date: 20137 (yyddd, 137th day of 2020) and I would like to see the output as 16-Sep-2020
Ref: http://www.longpelaexpertise.com/toolsJulian.php

Could someone help the logic in Javascript? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to try something and then ask for help if that doesnt work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using [moment](https://momentjs.com/docs/):

```
const moment = require('moment');
console.log(moment("20137", "YYDDD").format("DD-MMMM-YYYY"));   // 16-May-2020
```

Comment: What is the inverse if I have a data and need a YYDDD Julian date?

Comment: use this if you want to convert the Date into Julian date: moment("08-04-2023", "DD-MM-YYYY").format("YYYYDDD")